# flutter: what is the role of dart:ui library?

Tags: flutter, dart, frameworks

I'm learning the framework of flutter. The lowest level of dart framework is `dart:ui library`, I have searched the [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html#:%7E:text=To%20use%2C%20import%20dart%3Aui,%2C%20layout%2C%20and%20rendering%20subsystems.) and it's described as below. But I couldn't understand this well.

```
 This library exposes the lowest-level services that Flutter frameworks
 use to bootstrap applications, such as classes for driving the input,
 graphics text, layout, and rendering subsystems.
```

I have some basic knowledge and experience of painting pages but this is the first time to learn about the underlying principle. Could you please explain it clearer how it works in `flutter`, for example, how it connects the upper layer and the `flutter engine`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried reading https://www.flutterinternals.org/?

Comment: btw, they have nice "Export as PDF" button on the right top corner...

Comment: @pskink oh thanks for your advice, I will check it.

Comment: sure, your welcome